# Is there a zsh add-on or an iTerm addon that allows arbitrary string autocompletions?

Tags: macos, zsh, autocomplete, iterm2

I often find myself staring at a string that was printed in my terminal, I need to use it in a command, but don't want to move the mouse to copy/paste it.

I'm wondering if `zsh` or iTerm support arbitrary auto-completion, from arbitrary strings in the terminal buffer (not necessarily things I've typed, maybe things that got printed).

I know it must exist (I know I'm not the only keyboard freak), but I can't find it. All I've managed to find is auto-completers for directories, files or specific commands like git.

Comment: If you wrap your session in a multiplexer like tmux, you can do copy paste from the screen with just the keyboard [tmux copy paste](https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the iTerm [Highlights for New Users](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-highlights.html).

Arbitrary autocomplete with `CMD+;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if that string is being outputted to the terminal by previous command then this might help:

```
zmodload -I zsh/parameter
insert-last-command-output () {
    LBUFFER+="$(eval $history[$((HISTCMD-1))])"
}
zle -N insert-last-command-output
bindkey '^[x' insert-last-command-output
```

Put it in your zshrc. `ALT-x` will now insert result of that last command onto your command line.